# Calling an API from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to get results from an API inside in a stored procedure but the result is null. I cannot represent the actual call because it contains sensitive information but it has this logic:

```
EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Select @hResult as Create1 --@hResult=0 --> Create OK

EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',@WebAPI,'false'
Select @hResult as Get1 --@hResult=0 --> GET OK

EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Select @hResult as SEND1 --@hResult=0 --> SEND OK

declare @XML table(yourXML XML) INSERT @xml ( yourXML )
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseXML.xml'
Select @hResult as Response1 --@hResult=0 --> Response OK

Select * from @XML
```

I tested the query outside the SQL server and it works properly. I called a dummy API ('https://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed') from the SQL server and the results was OK.

Since the output is long i tried to store the results into table or XML variable but the result was still null.

The API will return either JSON either XML. For example a result set would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route code="200" message="OKs">
    <cross_seca>false</cross_seca>
    <total_distance>14417.8587</total_distance>
    <total_seca_distance>0.0</total_seca_distance>
    <section>
        <from_port seca_port="true">CORINTH</from_port>
        <to_port seca_port="false">PUSAN</to_port>
        <distance>14417.8587</distance>
        <distance_seca>0.0</distance_seca>
        <waypoint lat="37.9333000183105" lon="22.9500007629395" name="CORINTH" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="37.9612731933594" lon="22.9347362518311" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="38.0481071472168" lon="22.8005352020264" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="38.2301750183105" lon="22.4502639770508" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="38.3078460693359" lon="22.0923881530762" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="38.3470115661621" lon="21.9775218963623" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="38.3525581359863" lon="21.8507251739502" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="38.3245086669922" lon="21.7836151123047" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="1.5563510656357" lon="108.975273132324" name="KALIMANTAN WEST (RP)" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="3.5768096446991" lon="110.003883361816" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="17.2663631439209" lon="118.031089782715" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="21.8487491607666" lon="121.073471069336" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="22.5359420776367" lon="121.593360900879" name="LAN YU IS. (RP)" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="34.9842147827148" lon="129.087631225586" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="35.0500526428223" lon="129.164993286133" seca="false"/>
        <waypoint lat="35.1067888889" lon="129.0624694444" name="PUSAN" seca="false"/>
    </section>
</route>
```

Why I cannot get results through the SQL server?

EDIT1:
The API provides information about how many times it has return results. When I call it from the SQL server, it returns null but the API had sent all the information.

EDIT2:

- When I run the web API at Postman it runs OK.
- If I copy the results and create a mock API to give me the same result set, and call the mock API from the SQL server it works fine
- (!) If I call the API from server, all hResults report as 0 (success) but the ultimate select on the array comes back null

EDIT3:

There is some issue, when calling an **https** API from the procedure. When I try to call **http** API works just fine.

Comment: Don't call web methods from stored procedures. There are countless reasons that make this a poor choice. Call it from a separate app.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I understand that this is not a proper way to do this, but because there is an architecture issue at the moment. This is the only way to solve it.

Comment: I can't think of any sane DBA who would ban the use of CLR integration but allow the OLE automation stored procedures to be used - so I'd strongly suggest (if you *have* to have this call done at all, see Remus's comment) that it be done via a CLR stored proc.

Comment: How do you obtain the xml you pasted. probrably an authentication issue

Comment: Why can't you call a script (i.e. powershell) that makes the web call then inserts the results into the table?

Comment: @AbBennett I got the result from another source, in order to represent the result set. I cannot get result from the SQL server.

Comment: What other source. Can u execute the API in a browser? Use a tool like postman to test this.

Comment: @AbBennett As I mentioned on my question: I tested the API outside the SQL server and it works properly. I did the test on postman to be precise.

Comment: What `HRESULT` values you get at each step? It will be the *return* value of `sp_OAMethod`

Comment: also [`responseText `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762275(v=vs.85).aspx) is a property, so you neet to use [`sp_OAGetProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oagetproperty-transact-sql)

Comment: And I doubt the `open` call can translate the `false` to a `VARIANT_FALSE`. Try passing a [short 0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923), which in T-SQL is `smallint`.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I updated the question with Hresults. Everything works fine except the response at the end.

Comment: What about the HRESULT from `exec sp_OAGetProperty @object, 'Status'`? Also, did you try `sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'ResponseText'`? (since `Status` works, but the documentation is lower case...)

Comment: @RemusRusanu I belive the error lies at ResponseText OUTPUT. The variable for some reason cannot hold all the information of the XML file. The XML contains roughly 6000 characters and I tried to store in varchar(8000) or XML variable, but the same error pops up. When I delete a bunch or rows at XML file and use mocky to fetch this new file everything works fine.

Comment: You can try `nvarchar(MAX)`, but I doubt it will work since `sp_OAxxx` predates the MAX types and is unlikely to have been updated for them. I also doubt the old `TEXT` type will work, but you can try.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I fixed the problem of the size by creating a temporary Array to show the results. I updated the question and the only problem now is the EDIT2.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I reconfigured the DB and finally made it with CLR stored proc. But now I am wondering why http can be called and https cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could call any HTTP but not HTTPS from the procedure due to the missing Client Certificate. I copied the certificate from the browser and the call was successful. Postman and browsers have built-in function to acquire the certificates.

But in any case straight HTTP calls from procedures should be discouraged as it is mentioned on the comments here.